# How to get input value from react-native-element

Tags: react-native

In React Native 16.

**Get input value**

```
<Input
 ...
 onChange={event => getValue(event)}
 />
```

**Output value**

```
const getValue = event => {
   console.log(event.nativeEvent.text);
 };
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Input` component from `react-native-elements` is basically rendering the [TextInput](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput) component. So you can use `onChangeText` instead of `onChange` like

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Input } from 'react-native-elements';

export default function UselessTextInput() {
  const [value, onChangeText] = React.useState('Useless Placeholder');

  return (
    <Input
      onChangeText={text => onChangeText(text)}
      value={value}
    />
  );
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Nice syntax !!. Great

Answer (score 0):

Set value to the state.

```
const getValue = event => {
   this. setState({text: event.nativeEvent.text});
 };
```